# Can not draw more than 8 nodes by networkx raising `NetworkXError: Node 8 has no position` error

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to draw graph by networkx. However, the below code suffers the error that is

> NetworkXError: Node 8 has no position

I believe only less than seven nodes are allowed, but I can not understand why.

Please suggest why the error happens and how to fix to draw more than 8 nodes.

```
import networkx as nx

# new_words = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"] => It does not occur the error
new_words = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
target_word = ["0"]

G=nx.cubical_graph()
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=[0],
                       node_color='r',
                       node_size=50, alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=range(1, len(new_words)+1),
                       node_color='w',
                       node_size=50, alpha=0.8)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,
                       edgelist=[(0,i) for i in range(1,len(new_words)+1)])


# some math labels
labels={}
labels[0]=target_word
for idx in range(0,len(new_words)):
    labels[idx+1] = new_words[idx]

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels)
```

The error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetworkXError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-5ddab3dbe0d6> in <module>()
     15                        nodelist=range(1, len(new_words)+1),
     16                        node_color='w',
---> 17                        node_size=50, alpha=0.8)
     18 
     19 nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,

/Users/sudou/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.pyc in draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist, node_size, node_color, node_shape, alpha, cmap, vmin, vmax, ax, linewidths, label, **kwds)
    384         xy = numpy.asarray([pos[v] for v in nodelist])
    385     except KeyError as e:
--> 386         raise nx.NetworkXError('Node %s has no position.'%e)
    387     except ValueError:
    388         raise nx.NetworkXError('Bad value in node positions.')

NetworkXError: Node 8 has no position.
```

Comment: It would help others to show, where the exception is thrown (which line)

Comment: @Andreas_D Thanks. I added the error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

`nx.cubical_graph()` has 8 nodes.  Namely `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.  You have sent a `nodelist` that includes node `8` which is not part of your graph.  The graph you are drawing is the graph of a cube - 8 nodes (the vertices) and 12 edges (the edges of the cube).

You're asking it to plot 9 nodes of an 8 node graph.  Thus it cannot find where that node goes.

Responding to your question on how to plot more than 8 nodes in a graph, you have to start with a graph with more than 8 nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to draw a labeled graph which contains more than 9 nodes?

Comment: Yes of course.  But the graph itself has to have all the nodes you list in the `nodelist`.  Unless you have a reason to specify a subset of the nodes, you shouldn't even include the optional `nodelist` argument.